# Webcam forced resolution changer

Tags: video, webcam, live-preview

I am looking for a software that force sets the (plugged in) webcams resolutions to 640x360 widescreen. I am using VH Multicamera Studio and it has some problems with setting the webcam to widescreen.

Thank you!